# Core Data transactions from Public database are coming very slow

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I'm developing an app that uses CloudKit as it's main database. I have a relatively small database (around 200 entries, each with 2-3 relationships) that I offer pre-populated as as the public database (new in iOS 14).

I noticed that the **CK mirroring is very very slow**. I get the first 5-6 transactions in a matter of seconds an that I have to wait around 2 minutes for all the data to populate.

As I can't show partial results (I can't allow the user to see the main entity if it's relations are not fetched yet) this is a big problem for me.

Is there a way to speed up the CK mirroring process? (make it more efficient)?

How can I diagnose what is taking that much? Apple recommended in the last WWDC to use this public database as an initial set of data, but people will get frustrated if the initial app load takes 2 minutes :o

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda expected behaviour, lets say for example you have 500 entries without any relationships and you want to fetch then with `CKQueryOperation`, when the operation is added to the public container it will not return all of the 500 entries at once, it will return at least 100 then it will query for the next 100 using the cursor and so on.

Edit

> Is there a way to speed up the CK mirroring process? (make it more
> efficient)?

No

These operations are maybe slow because of network issues, you should take that in consideration.

Comment: I can understand that, but what is a desirable approach to ease the pain on the user? I believe no-one will understand why the app loads in 2 minutes.

I tried using a "seeded" sqlite file. It works but when its loaded on different device, I get 'NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateWillResetSyncNotificationName' with reason: 'AccountChange'

Comment: To ease the pain haha, you can use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification to show loading indicator for example? iOS 14+ only ..

Comment: or don't use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer for public database, use the CloudKit functions it is faster of course.

Comment: well, yes, I already implemented something similar, but the problem is now I have an entire UI full of spinners.

Comment: what I can't understand is why they implemented this CoreData+CK for public databases. Its obvious users have some initial dataset that needs to be populated.

Comment: I can't help you to speed up the process of core data to apply those changes from the cloud, if you find a way please let me know.

Comment: What is working like a charm is the seeded .sqlite files in the app bundle (if starting from the original device). If I could trick CKMirror to ignore the fact they ware created by another user, I'm done